# Modify "ExpectationNotMet" output in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm using Ruby, Rspec and Cucumber to run tests. I have something like this:

`expect(@response.code).to eql(200)`

And when the parameter is not 200, the following output is shown:

```
(compared using eql?)
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/accounts_steps.rb:159:in `/^I see an? '(accepted|created|ok)' (create|authorization|payment|confirmation) response$/' features/honduras/honduras-claro-bundle-postpay.feature:9:in 
Then I see an 'accepted' create response
```

I need to add some relevant information to this output, so I want to modify it. I would like to modify the built-in matcher for this exception, if such thing is possible. Could someone please help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [customized message](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message):

```
expect(@response.code).to eql(200), "Expected to respond with 200 OK, but got #{@response.code}"
```

But matcher `eql` should print message like this by default:

```
   expected: 200
        got: 404
```